# Regex website path

Tags: php, regex

I have a bit of an unusual question, I think.  I'm working on a project (in PHP / MySQL) where a user can supply a path written as a regular expression, and the site will load some content based off of that.  So say, for example, someone supplies this regular expression:

```
articles\/([0-9]+)$
```

When someone visits http://example.com/articles/3, it will load that particular page with its content and settings associated with it.  All of these paths are stored in a MySQL database.  When a user visits the site, it checks the URL against the database of regular expressions and finds the appropriate content to display.

Here's my problem: A user can associate any number of regular-expression paths with any number of other pages, and they can be very similar to any other regular expressions.  My immediate thought would be to narrow down a search based off of the beginning of the URL (after example.com/, of course), and peek through all of the options until it finds an exact match.  I'm concerned, though, because in the worst case it could look through dozens if not more of options before finding an exact match...and that would waste valuable resources.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how I could improve the system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If that regex match number is a primary key in your table, the performance shouldn't even be a problem (should take a fraction of a second), assuming you have less than a million articles in your website.

Also use caching to improve performance.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, indices won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion would be to cache the results of the matches in another mysql table. Searching that will be fast since its indexed, then if no match is found, go through your regexes and apply them. When regexes are deleted or updated, remember to remove the cache associated with that regex.